# Should the background dataset for shap be standardized?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, shap

So I am trying to explain a basic SVM model using SHAP. The inputs to the SVM model however are standardized (I used `StandardScaler().fit()` and then transformed the datapoints using `StandardScaler` so that they can be used on the SVM model).

My question is now when using SHAP I need to give it a background distribution. Usually the input to this background distribution looks like this:

```
background_distribution = KMeans(n_clusters=10,random_state=0).fit(xtrain).cluster_centers_
```

However I wanted to use my own custom background distribution, which contains select data points. Does this mean the data points need to be standardized as well? i.e instead of looking like

```
[ 1 0 1 31 24 4817 2 3 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
```

they look like this

```
[ 0.67028006 -0.18887347 0.90860212 -0.41342579 0.26204266 0.55080012
-0.85479154 0.13743146 -0.70749448 -0.42919754 1.21628074 -0.71418983
-0.26726124 -0.52247913 -0.34755864 0.31234752 -0.23208655 -0.63565412
-0.40904178 0. 4.89897949 -0.23473314 0.64082627 -0.46852129
-0.26726124 -0.44542354 1.15657353 0.53795751]
```

For clarity: I am asking whether after retrieving my points, I need to standardize the background data set, since my original data points are scaled for use in the model, however my background distribution contains non scaled data points.

The model training looks like this:

```
ss = StandardScaler().fit(X)
xtrain = ss.transform(xtrain) #Changes values to make them ML compatible -not needed for trees
xtest = ss.transform(xtest)

support_vector_classifier = SVC(kernel='rbf')
support_vector_classifier.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
y_pred_svc = support_vector_classifier.predict(xtest)
```

Option A:

```
background_distribution= [ 1 0 1 31 24 4817 2 3 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
shap.KernelExplainer(support_vector_classifier.predict,background_distribution)
```

Option B:

```
background_distribution= [ 1 0 1 31 24 4817 2 3 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
ss = StandardScaler().fit(background_distribution)
background_distribution = ss.transform(background_distribution)
shap.KernelExplainer(support_vector_classifier.predict,background_distribution)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Option B. Your background should be preprocessed in the same way as your training data

is close.

This is the case in any situation in ML when you preprocess data -- should you split your data for train, test, validate, should you feed your data for prediction to trained model -- you always apply the same transformations to all parts of your data, sometimes manually, sometimes through pipeline. SHAP is not an exception from this principle.

However, you may think about the following as well: your scaler should be trained on the **trained data** before applying to test or background data. You can't train it on test or validate or background data because this would sound as if for predicting future you first asking to show it to you ("data leakage" as they call it ML).

This means, you can't:

```
ss = StandardScaler().fit(background_distribution)
background_distribution = ss.transform(background_distribution)
```

Rather:

```
ss = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
background_distribution = ss.transform(background_distribution)
```